# How to get nested element in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

> This is my full Document and I need only it's  subblock 'One' or 'two' at a time.

```
{
"_id": ObjectId('12abc'),
"createdAt": ISODate('2016-04-04T06:04:53.486Z'),
"updatedAt": ISODate('2016-04-04T06:04:53.486Z'),
"updatedBy": "SSE",
"DocName": "doc1",
"MainObj": {
    "One": {
        "color": {
            "green": [
                {
                    "val": "01",
                    "val2": "0"
                },
                {
                    "val": "10",
                    "val2": "5"
                }
            ],
            "result": "0000"
             }
         }

    "Two": {
        "color1": {
            "blue": [
                {
                    "val": "01",
                    "val2": "0"
                },
                {
                    "val": "10",
                    "val2": "5"
                }
            ],
            "result": "0000"
             }
                    }
               }
}
```

> This is my expected block:
>       One": {
>               "color": {
>                   "green": [
>                       {
>                           "val": "01",
>                           "val2": "0"
>                       },
>                       {
>                           "val": "10",
>                           "val2": "5"
>                       }
>                   ],
>                   "result": "0000"
>                    }
>                           }
>                      }

Comment: As I can see there is 1 extra parenthesis. Kindly check and post correct collection.

Comment: @Himanshu,  Corrected. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the aggregation framework by projecting the subdocument (`MainObj.One`) into a variable called One and then returning just that variable. For example:

```
db.YourCollectionName.aggregate([
    {$project:{One:"$MainObj.One"}},
    {$project:{_id:0,One:1}}
]);
```

Returns this:

```
{ "One" : { "color" : { "green" : [ { "val" : "01", "val2" : "0" }, { "val" : "10", "val2" : "5" } ], "result" : "0000" } } }
```

More on the aggregation framework and the `$project` operator:

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/

**Update: Here is the code to include createdAt, updatedAt, updatedBy, and DocName:**

```
db.YourCollectionName.aggregate([
    {$project:{One:"$MainObj.One",createdAt:"$createdAt",updatedAt:"$updatedAt",updatedBy:"$updatedBy",DocName:"$DocName"}},
    {$project:{_id:0,One:1,createdAt:1,updatedAt:1,updatedBy:1,DocName:1}}
]);
```

Returns:

```
{
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-04-04T06:04:53.486Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-04-04T06:04:53.486Z"),
    "updatedBy" : "SSE",
    "DocName" : "doc1",
    "One" : {
        "color" : {
            "green" : [ { "val" : "01", "val2" : "0" }, { "val" : "10", "val2" : "5" } ],
            "result" : "0000" 
        }
    }
}
```

Note: A much simpler way to do this would be as follows:

```
db.YourCollectionName.find({},{createdAt:1,updatedAt:1,updatedBy:1,DocName:1,"MainObj.One":1});
```

The only difference is that this would return `One` as a sub-document of `MainObj` (which is different than what was asked in the original question):

```
{
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-04-04T06:04:53.486Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-04-04T06:04:53.486Z"),
    "updatedBy" : "SSE",
    "DocName" : "doc1",
    "MainObj" : {
        "One" : {
            "color" : {
                "green" : [ { "val" : "01", "val2" : "0" }, { "val" : "10", "val2" : "5" } ], 
                "result" : "0000"
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mark, Can you please tell me how can I get below fields along with existing result fields                                                                        "createdAt": ISODate('2016-04-04T06:04:53.486Z'),
"updatedAt": ISODate('2016-04-04T06:04:53.486Z'),
"updatedBy": "SSE",
"DocName": "doc1",

Comment: See my updated answer with instructions for getting the fields.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks a ton Mark !!